# PHP - Creating Multiple Conditional Statements For a Single Element

Tags: php, html, mysql, css

I'm still new in PHP and I need to know how I can create two or more conditional statements for a single elements. For instance, maybe if I had a form that I wanted to perform a certain action if some conditions were true.

I understand that one of the way is to group the statements like:

```
if(arg1 && arg2 && arg3) {
echo "All of these statements are true";
}
```

How can I separate this condition but making sure that it executes at the same time?

Comment: Can you be more specific about what you are trying to do?  You can simply nest multiple `if` statements if you want to...

Answer (score 3):

You can use nested `if` statements to accomplish the same check.

```
if(arg1)
{
    if(arg2)
    {
        if(arg3) 
        {
            echo "All of these statements are true";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Alright. Sorry for not being specific enough. Suppose I had a form that I wanted it: Check if the that the all fields have been filled in before it's submitted, and it must echo something out if that condition is not met. I also wanted, for the same form, to check if the username field doesn't contain digits. how would I go about writing that? You don't have to give the full coding. A basic syntax would do.

Comment: @Mosire If you want to check the fields before it's submitted, your have to use client-side (javascript) not server-side (php). You would have to submit the form then do your verification if you want to use php. http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=javascript+validate+form+before+submit

Comment: @Mosire You should start in checking for isset and !empty values from form and then analyze each `$_POST` with some more if statements. Tha's basic logic. You should start fro here and post a new question once you will find problems with your code

Comment: @Mosire about my answer I think it was correct, so please accept it and upvote if you feel the same.

Comment: haha! No doubt Fabio, you've been interacting with me a lot the past couple days and I'm thankful. @Sean, there's ways to go about it in PHP as well... One more question Fabio, is it okay if the 'if' statements don't have the else statement sometimes? Maybe, when I don't want and opposing action?

Comment: @Mosire yes it is totally correct, you are not supposed to use `else` if you don't need to

Answer (score 3):

Try this.

```
   if(($something == 1 ) && ($someotherthing !=7) && ($something == 2)) {
    echo "All of these statements are true";
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Changed answer after what I understood of you clarification:

If you want to know if the posted form has all the required fields in PHP then you could write :

```
if(isset($_POST['field_name']) && $_POST['field_name'] != "")
{
    //The field is set and not empty.
}
else
{
    echo "Field not set...";
}
```

w3schools tutorial on forms :
http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_forms.asp

As for the numeric part of your question take a look at regex :
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9099/The-30-Minute-Regex-Tutorial

EDIT 2 : As someone mentioned if you want to know if the field is set BEFORE being sent to the server, you will need to use Javascript.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I think I wasn't specific enough. Please check the comment that I have made on Fabio's answer.